# Internet performance on u-boot

Tags: networking, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

I'm looking for a way to run `iperf -s` command on u-boot. Is there any option in u-boot build configuration to enable iperf utility as available in Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, and it is unlikely that it could be easily ported.

Comment: U-Boot supports UDP only. The interesting part for U-Boot in the inbound speed. Implementing an iperf UDP server look like a straight forward task.